# How to connect to a database using Sequalize - Mocha Node and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, mocha.js

Completely new to Mocha/Sequelize I'm afraid.

I am trying to establish a simple connection to a database using Sequelize with Mocha Node and javascript.

This is the code I am using:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
        
describe('Confirm connection to database', () => {
    it('Connect To Database', () => {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname'); 
        sequelize
            .authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.info('INFO - Database connected.')
            })
            .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR - Unable to connect to the database:', err)
        })
        
    })})
```

The test passes everytime but I don't see 'INFO - Database connected.' or 'ERROR - Unable to connect to the database:' in the console log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in the end:

```
describe('Connect to the Database', () => {
    it('Connect to the Database and check the connection is successful', async () => {
        var sql;
        var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
        sql = new Sequelize("databasename", "username", "password", {
            host: "sqlservername",
            port: "1433",
            dialect: "mssql"
            }

        try{
            var test = await sql.authenticate()
            console.log("We have successfully connected to the database!");
            }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("Connection to the database failed!: " + e.message);
            throw e;
            }
    
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing dialect.

You can try this.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sql = new Sequelize("{database name}", "{username}",
 "{password}", {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "49394",
  dialect: "mssql",
  operatorsAliases: false
 });

var test = sql.authenticate()
    .then(function () {
        console.log("INFO - Database connected.");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("ERROR - Unable to connect to the database:", err);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks I have changed the code but I am now seeing "SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" every time. It works correctly when i connect using MS SQL Server Management Studio. I can't understand why sequelize can't find it?

Comment: For `mssql` you want to use different dialect